# Values from drop-down list in Form are not being capture and pass (Angular)

Tags: angular

I am trying to add functionality so a user can update a review. So far they can update the text field but not the stars field as the value selected from the drop-down list is not being passed.

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="review">Please edit your review below</label>
        <textarea id="editedreview" rows="3" name="editedreview" class="form-control" formControlName="editedreview"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="stars">Please provide a rating (5 = best)</label>
        <select id="editstars" name="editstars" class="form-control" formControlName="editstars">
            <option value="1">1 star</option>
            <option value="2">2 stars</option>
            <option value="3">3 stars</option>
            <option value="4">4 stars</option>
            <option value="5">5 stars</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- <span *ngIf="isIncomplete()">
            You must complete all fields</span> -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Component.ts file

```
onSubmit() {
    this.webService.editReview(this.editForm.value);
    console.log(this.editForm.value);
    this.editForm.reset();
}
```

web.service file

```
editReview(review) {
    let postData = new FormData();
    postData.append("text", review.editedreview);
    postData.append("stars", review.editstars);
    this.http.put(
        'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/movies/' +
         this.movieID + '/reviews/' + this.reviewID, postData
    ).subscribe(response => {
        console.log("Edit - Success");
    })
}
```

The console log is only show the value from textarea being captured. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show where you initialize your formGroup?

Comment: I have now fixed it but you were right, I left out the editstars field when initializing the formgroup.

Comment: perfect ! bye :)